# Which control can be added to show that the application is not hanging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

It's a windows form application. I want to make the user feel that the application is running. Should I use animations that will continuously animate to make the user feel that it is running? Or can anything else be done?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows forms, WPF, etc.

Comment: Its windows forms

Comment: Don't edit that back in again.

Comment: If you're blocking the UI thread, it doesn't matter if you throw a .gif in an image control on the form--the UI thread won't be available to animate it.  This is why you move long-running work on a background thread and update the UI once done (or every 500 or so MS if you want to show the user progress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was you I'd place a label on the Form. And it's text should scroll through the characters of |/-\ . Update the label every now and then. Eg. after each calculation of the loop, advance to the next character.

It is unclear whether this is vba or vb.net question, if it is vba, after advancing to the next character call the doEvents built-in function. 
(update: now I see that the question tags were updated properly, thanks).

In the case of VB.net, I think you need the [Control.Update()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) function once the label is advanced to the next character.

Comment: nice idea. How about adding animations since they make the ui look beautiful

Comment: I'm not familiar with using gifs on a userform, though I think that is what you have to loop up for. 
For your second question though you should make a separate post (accordingly to the StackOverflow guidelines). If you think that my answer answered your question, then please give it a green tick.  :)

Comment: Alternatively you can still have some textual log or status bar on the bottom. That also gives a feedback to the user.

Comment: @KuharanBhowmik just want to note that animations do not "make ui look beautiful". They have a purpose (mostly indication of transition from one state to another or drawing user attention to somehing important). Animations that were made because they are "beautiful" are just annoying and useless.

Answer (score 0):

you can use progressbar along with background working control. Here is link to use it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx